# How do I clone an object for the purposes of moving something and seeing if the move is valid? (Java, Chess)

Tags: java, oop, class, object, chess

I am writing a simple chess-playing game. I won't post it all here, but I'll give you the necessary details.

I move by clicking a square with a piece on it, then the square becomes selected, and then clicking where I want to piece to move. Sometimes in chess, a move may fail to respond to check or create a check on one's own king and is therefore illegal. The best way, I've found, to decide whether a move is illegal is to make a move on an "ifBoard" (a clone of the board) and if I deem the move legal, set the real board equal to the ifBoard.

Here is a code snippet of me responding to mouse clicks (board is the real board, destination is the clicked square, selectedSquare is the square previously selected(if not null))

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            Square selectedSquare = board.selectedSquare();
            Square destination = board.getSquare(e.getX(), e.getY());
            board.deselect();
            if(destination == null){
                repaint();
                return;
            }

            if(selectedSquare == null){
                System.out.println("SelectedSquare is null");
                if(destination.occupiedByTeam(turn)){
                    System.out.println("destination is occupied by right team and is null");
                    board.select(destination);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(!selectedSquare.occupiedByTeam(turn)){
                    System.out.println("SelectedSquare not occupied by correct team");
                    repaint();
                    return;
                }

                if(destination.occupiedByTeam(turn)){
                    System.out.println("ChosenSquare occupied by same team");
                    board.select(destination);
                    repaint();
                    return;
                }

                //move on a dummy board and check for conflicts
                Board ifBoard = (Board)board.clone();

                System.out.println(ifBoard.toString());
                System.out.println(board.toString());
                //check if you can't move due to piece movement limitations
//.place() is a coordinate of the square on the tile system (A-H and 1-8)
                if(
                !ifBoard.move((int)selectedSquare.place().getX(), (int)selectedSquare.place().getY(), (int)destination.place().getX(), (int)destination.place().getY())
                ){
                    repaint();
                    return;
                }

                //if moving results in self-check
                if(ifBoard.check(turn)){
                    //don't move
                    repaint();
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    //move
                    System.out.println("Board moved!");
                    board = new Board(ifBoard);
                    cycleTurns();
                }
            }

            repaint();
        }
```

The toString calls are registering differently, but I have narrowed the problem down to the ifBoard.move() call actually moving the real board.

Here is the board class, or part of it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.Cloneable;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Board implements Cloneable{
    private Square[][] squares;

    private Rectangle2D squareWrap;
    private Rectangle2D boardBorder;

    private Square selectedSquare;

    public Board(){
        squares = new Square[8][8];
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                squares[i][j] = new Square(new Point2D.Double(i, j));
            }
        }

        boardBorder = new Rectangle2D.Double(Constants.boardX,
                                             Constants.boardY,
                                             Constants.borderWidth * 2 + Constants.boardSide,
                                             Constants.borderHeight * 2 + Constants.boardSide);

        squareWrap = new Rectangle2D.Double(Constants.boardX + Constants.borderWidth,
                                            Constants.boardY + Constants.borderHeight,
                                            Constants.boardSide,
                                            Constants.boardSide);

        selectedSquare = null;
    }

    public Object clone() {
        Board obj = new Board();
        obj.setSquares(this.squares);
        obj.setSelectedSquare(this.selectedSquare);

        return obj;
    }...
```

Am I cloning incorrectly? Is there a better way? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I cloning incorrectly? Is there a better way?

The clone method should always start by calling `super.clone()` for reasons that I won't go into in this post.

Also, you're not cloning the attributes of the object (you're doing a shallow copy instead of a deep copy). Thus a cloned Board would *share* the same reference to the `squares` structure. (Changing the cloned Board would change the original Board.)

(Many people argue that you should avoid `clone` and `Cloneable` all together though.)

If I were you, I would strongly consider making the Board class immutable and perhaps go with some copy-on-write mechanism. That would save you a lot of headache I believe.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the difference between shallow and deep copies now. Also I like the idea of having Board immutable, and I'll look into how to implement a copy-on-write mechanism.

Comment: Could you, by chance, point me to a good Java copy-on-write implementation, so I could learn how to make one? I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem might be that your clone() implementation does not create a deep copy. The cloned object shares a least some state with the instance it is cloned from. By that, I mean they are referencing the same objects:

```
public Object clone() {
    Board obj = new Board();
    obj.setSquares(this.squares); // Square instances are the same for both boards
    return obj;
}
```

If you change state on the clone - e.g. on a square - you also change it on the real board.

From what you've posted, you are calling `ifBoard.move()`. If that method affects part of the "shared state" then it will affect both board instances.

Comment: Thank you. This was also correct, but given that I had to pick an answer I picked the more detailed (and earlier) one below.